# array of $x$ and $y$ in an implicit plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, implicit-function

If I use implicit plot of a relation (say $x\cdot y+\sin(x+y)=0$ ) and obtain a plot. How do I get the list/array of the values of $x$ and $y$ plotted?

Answer (score 0):

How accurate do you need the values to be? To get a 2D array of points satisfying an equation, you could just make a grid with boundaries $a_x,b_x$ and $a_y,b_y$ and steps $h_x,h_y$, then substitute every point into the equation and assign some small tolerance $t$ such that if $$x_n y_m+\sin(x_n+y_m) < t$$ then the point approximately satisfies the equation. Then you make a loop through all the points and obtain an array corresponding to an approximate implicit plot.

Comment: I will check it. Thanks